# Should I have these directives in my Nginx config?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

I'm using just Rails straight with Nginx (no apache), and wondering if I even need the following in my virtual hosts:

```
        # serve static content directly
        location ~* \.(ico|jpg|gif|png|css|js|swf|html)$ {
          if (-f $request_filename) {
            expires max;
            break;
          }
        }
```

Is it even relevant if I'm not using Apache?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using Rails, probably the only config you need is just:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        root path/to/static/files;
        try_files $uri @rails;
        expires max;
    }

    location @rails {
        # proxy_pass to gunicorn or whatever...
    }
}
```

But it is always better to keep all media files in a separate directory:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.org;

    location / {
        # proxy_pass to gunicorn or whatever...
    }

    location /media/ {
        root path/to/static/files;
        try_files $uri @rails;
        expires max;
    }
}
```

Leave ugly and complicated rules like:

```
location ~* \.(ico|jpg|gif|png|css|js|swf|html)$`
```

to PHP-folks. They usually have a mess of code and media in their projects and like programming in web-server configs instead of doing all the application logic in application.

Comment: Is the `location /media/` needed at all to serve static content? I use CloudFront CDN to serve all static files *EXCEPT* HTML.

Comment: I don't know is it needed in your case or not, it highly depends on your project. There's no magic in the `location` directive. Please, read: http://nginx.org/r/location and http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html

Answer (score 1):

This directive tells *nginx* to set the `expires` header to largest possible value and to stop processing further directives when requested file ends with one of those extensions and exists. Those files will be served by nginx. This is valid directive whether you use apache or not. You don't **have** to use it, but you better do because nginx is very good at serving static files.

#### Update

As other people pointed out, you should avoid using `if`. You can do this by:

```
location ~* \.(ico|jpg|gif|png|css|js|swf|html)$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    expires max;
}
```

if you want to do special processing, use *named locations*:

```
location ~* \.(ico|jpg|gif|png|css|js|swf|html)$ {
    try_files $uri @process_404;
    expires max;
}

location @process_404{
    # do your stuff
}
```

Comment: But how about the ifIsEvil: http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil If you're already trying with the location directive to sort out static files. Why the -f $request_filename?

Comment: `try_files $uri =404;` - it's just way to add surplus `stat()` call on every request.

Answer (score 1):

This `if` is meaningless and just wasting of your cpu.

From documentation:

> Enables or disables adding or modifying the “Expires” and “Cache-Control” response header fields provided that the response code equals 200, 201, 204, 206, 301, 302, 303, 304, or 307.

@ http://nginx.org/r/expires

Do you see 404 here? I do not.

> Stops processing the current set of ngx_http_rewrite_module directives.

@ http://nginx.org/r/break

And I see no other rewrite directives in your location.